# How to make blur effect without white light?

Tags: css

I use the following CSS property to set `blur` effect:

```
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
```

It makes div element `blur`, but I see white light at the corners of block, how can I make `blur effect` without them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to remove the blurred edges in a pure CSS way is by zooming the element a little bit then clipping the edges with `overflow: hidden` added to the container:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blur">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/7v0mtfyn/

Comment: Be careful, when using as blurred background though. transform: scale (); on full page background made scrolling incredibly laggy, both on Macbook and iPhone. The solution in this case was to make the background slightly bigger (110% let's say) and position it few pixels off the edge with overflow:hidden;

Comment: Nice it's perfect answer but can you take a look my code why it not work here when i am using same css code  [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mostofa/Ly7Lht3a/1/)

Comment: @MDMostofa add `#video-bg { width: 100%; }` >> https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/9h89crp1/

Comment: @Honza what makes it laggy? Is it the `blur` effect or the `transform` property? Also you could center the element with `position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; margin: auto;`

Comment: @Aziz this is not show right, You can check it again here it show white shadow of video all corner.
I want to remove this shadow. 
but if i use bluer it show .

Comment: @MDMostofa I am afraid that higher blur values increase the edge intensity and that creates a sort of transition effect. You could try adding a black background instead of white to contrast the page or apply more scale but scaling it further will make you lose more details, There is no other way around it for now unless if you manually blur the image or video (image/video editing software)...

Comment: It does not work, set simply background black to see white glow

Comment: I don't need use scale, what can you recommend me otherwise?